# Multiple parameters in a Axis webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, axis

This is my first time writing a web service client, it's funny, I have already written a webservice;)

Anyways, I am using axis to invoke the WS by following code

```
  String endpoint =
            "http://localhost:8080/SpeechServices/SpeechWebService/SpeechWebService";

    Service service = new Service();
    Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
    call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
    call.setOperationName(new QName("http://ws.ecw.com/", "parseNotes"));
    HashMap ret = (HashMap) call.invoke(new Object[]{"", "", ""});
    System.out.println("Sent 'Hello!', got '" + ret + "'");
```

My Service returns a HashMap and has three input parameters  apuId,providerId,notes
I am not sure how to send these parameters to the WS, I am sure it's just few method calls away ex; call.setProperty. Please advise

Comment: Okay I think it is addParameter() will check and confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, 
this is the answer, it does not completely work yet because Axis does not seem to be supporting hashmap as webservice response.

```
    String endpoint =
            "http://localhost:8080/eCWServices/StructSpeech/StructSpeech";
    Service service = new Service();
    Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
    call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
    call.setOperationName(new QName("http://ejb.ecw.com/", "parseNotes"));
    call.addParameter("notes", org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
    call.addParameter("apuId", org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
    call.addParameter("providerId", org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
    call.setReturnType(XMLType.SOAP_MAP);
    HashMap  ret = (HashMap) call.invoke(new Object[]{"","",""});
    System.out.println("Sent 'Hello!', got '" + ret + "'");
```